# push button value to firebase with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase

I am trying to load clicked button value to firebase database using jquery, javascript. but i keep failing in pushing the data to Firebase. can someone highlight why data is not pushed to DB

```
function saveData(){
    var selectedButton;
    document.getElementsById("cough").forEach(function(elm) {
    if (elm.checked) {
    selectedButton = elm.value;
    }
    });
    } 

    function insertData(selectedButton){
    var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref('users');
    firebaseRef.push({
    cough:selectedButton
    });
    }

     html:
     <div class="tab-pane active" id="cough" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center m-3">
            <div class=" card shadow shadow-sm">
                <div class="card-body ">
                    <img src="img/c2.png" class="d-block mx-auto img-fluid"/>
                    <h2 class="mb-5 text-center">Do you have cough?</h2>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <input type="button" id='cough' value="YES" class="nexttab btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control form-control-lg"  /> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <input type="button" id='cough' value="NO" class="nexttab btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control form-control-lg"  />  
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: `i keep getting error..` ? what error you got ? add that as well in your question

Comment: @Swati the data is not pushed to the firebase. the dabase is empty

Comment: you cannot have mutliple elements with same `ids` .Instead use class here also you never call your `insertData(selectedButton)` ? how data will get inserted then